# Array and map thread safety

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading

Two questions I want to ask with regards to java:

1. Given an array of objects, ObjectClass array[25] that's been initialized, would it be thread safe to pass such an array to multiple threads and have them use it only as a reference for information? None of the threads will change the contents of the array, just read from it.
2. Same question, but instead of an array, we have a map. I heard that modifying a map is not thread safe but simply reading from it is?

Thanks

Comment: What does "*tread safe*" mean for you?

Comment: Is initialization done in atomic manner?

Comment: Thread safe meaning that there's no compiler optimization that can somehow break something unexpectedly in ways I wouldn't foresee. Nothing more specific than this.

Comment: And no, initialization is not done in an atomic manner. The objects (and the array) are normally initialized (although in just one thread initially). The passing of the array to threads happens later on

Comment: "Thread safe meaning that there's no compiler optimization that can somehow break something unexpectedly in ways I wouldn't foresee" You can have thread unsafe code with or without compiler optimizations. This really isn't what is normally meant when somebody says "thread safety".

Comment: True, I guess a better way of putting it is getting unexpected behavior such as the array or map getting corrupt somehow because I didn't use any synchronization mechanisms while the threads read from them

Comment: As long as the initialization of the data structure *happens-before* (a term from the JLS) reading the structure, it will be "thread-safe" according to your definition. Rather than enumerating all the ways you can sufficiently synchronize threads, why don't you explain (or better yet, show some code) how you plan to pass the shared data to the consumer threads?

Comment: Concrete code won't be of much use in my opinion since the question is meant to be as general as possible. However, to make things easier, assume the following things: the array is a local object (declared within a method, it is initialized there as well and it is later passed via a constructor to another object that implements the runnable interface). The implemented run method reads from that array. Now, from the main thread, I start a bunch of objects that implement this runnable interface. All of them received the exact same unmodified array in their constructors

Comment: Re, "the question is meant to be as general as possible."  Moderators in this forum are encouraged to close questions that are "too broad."  This is meant to be a place where you ask for help with specific problems that are blocking you from completing some development task.  Not meant to be a forum for advice, guidelines, opinions, etc.

Comment: I assume "runnable" is `java.lang.Runnable` and "start a bunch of objects that implement this runnable interface" meant "start a bunch of `Thread` instances targeting this runnable. In that case, yes, you are totally fine because everything that happens before calling `start()` is visible to the new thread when it begins to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Reading contents of an array by multiple threads is thread-safe only
  if data isn't modified i.e. if you create the threads after you have
  filled the array However if you pass the initialized array to
  existing thread without synchronizing the data may be read out of
  sync.
- You may consider using java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap
  for #2 instead.

Comment: ...after you have filled _and safely published_ the array.  Google for "java safe publication".